# Event handler in JS for input mask plugin

Tags: javascript

I am using Jquery input mask plugin to handle timestamps. Writing the following code appends the plugin to all the relevant text boxes.

```
$('input[name="start-time"]').inputmask(
   "hh:mm:ss", {
       placeholder: "HH:MM:SS",
       insertMode: false,
       showMaskOnHover: false,
       hourFormat: "24"
   }
);
```

However, In my case I have dynamically generated text boxes as well. How do I get the input mask to be applied to those? I went through all the list of event handlers, and I wasn't able to find one which has on the creation of a new field, fire an event handler.

Comment: You can use class selector after you generated your input with above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input text is added dynamically, you can as well call the inputmask method for that element.
Another option would be to get notified when the element is added then call inputmask on the element.

```
$("<ancestor-element-selector>").on("DOMNodeInserted", 'input[name="start-time"]', function(){
    //call inputmask on the new element.    
    //$(this).inputmask(/*params...*/);
});
```